# Roots of $x^2-x+2=0 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory, integers

I've been challenged by a professor to find the roots of $x^2-x+2=0$ in the field $\mathbb{Z}_3[i] = \{a+bi \; \vert \; a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_3\}$. I used the "normal" quadratic formula and got roots of $2+2i$ and $2+i$, and was told there's a way without using the formula. Is there a method for this besides guessing and checking the nine elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$?

Comment: Perhaps you could say the roots are $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ (since $0$, $1$, and $2$ are not roots); the sum of roots of $x^2-tx+d$ is $t$, and the product is $d$, so we have $2a=1$, so $a=2$, and $a^2+b^2=2$, so $b^2=1$, so $b=1$ or $2$

Comment: Well, a silly way of doing it $x^2 -x + 2=0:: x^2+2=x:: x^2-1=x::(x+1)(x-1)=x$ and, um, one of $x-1,x,x+1$ must be purely imaginary and as it can't be $x$ (else $x^2 - x+2=purely real + purely imaginary + purelyreal \ne 0$). Likewise $x$ can't be purely real (else $x^2 =0,1$ so $x^2 -x +2=0$ means $x\ne 0\iff x=0$) so we have $\pm i(x\pm 1) = x$ and .... Oh, brother... that's just doing the four cases isn't it.

Comment: Well, I guess we can reduce 9 cases to 2 pretty easily once we rule out purely imaginary and purely real aren't possible and complex roots come in conjugate pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square (which leads to the quadratic formula):

$x^2-x+2=0$ $\iff x^2+2x+2=0$ $\iff (x+1)^2=-1$ $\iff x+1=\pm i$

$\iff x=2\pm i$ $\iff x=2+i\text{
 or }x=2+2i,$  since $-1=2 $ in $\mathbb Z_3$.

---

Alternatively, note that $0, 1, $ and $2$ are not roots, so the roots are complex conjugates $a\pm bi$.

The sum of the roots of $x^2-tx+d$ is $t$, so we have $(a+bi)+(a-bi)=2a=1;$ i.e., $a=2$.

The product of the roots of $x^2-tx+d$ is $d$, so we have $(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2=2; $

i.e., $b^2=1$.  Again we get the roots $a\pm bi=2\pm i$.

---

Really, though, checking the nine elements $\{0,\pm1,\pm i, \pm 1\pm i\}$ of $\mathbb Z_3[i]$ is not hard.

It is rather easy to see that $0$ and $\pm 1$ are not roots.

Nor is $\pm i$ since $i^2\mp i+2$ has an imaginary part.

Nor is $1+i$, since $(1+i)^2-(1+i)+2=2i-1-i+2$ also has an imaginary part,

so the roots must be the other pair of conjugates $-1\pm i$.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's better to think of $2=-1$. That way multiplication and exponentiation became a matter of just units, negatives, and zeros and magnitudes and growing values are just taken out of the picture altogether. Also noting that $1$ and $-1$ are "natural opposites" is just easy to intuit than $1$ and $2$.

So that said.....

======

Okay.  This may be kind of dumb but:

$x^2 -x +2 = 0\iff x^2-1 = x$

And

$x^2 -1=x$

$(x^2 -1)^2 = x^2$

$x^4 -2x^2 +1 = x^2$

$x^4 = -1$

$x^2 =\pm i$

And so $x^2 -1 = x\implies \pm i - 1 =x$

.... and that's it.  $x = -1 \pm i$.

However when we squared both sides we potentially added extraneous solutions.

So we must test these which easy enough.

(I had originally wanted to comment about roots coming in conjugate pairs but now that I've solved quicker than I expected we don't really need to.)

....

Not sure that a better way but I can say it didn't use the quadratic formula.

I wouldn't try it with any field more complex than $\mathbb Z_3[i]$.  The "all or nothing" nature of $Z_3$ allowed us to make a lot of draconian "either 0 or unit; either positive or negative" absolutes which wouldn't really occur in more "field-like" fields.

Comment: Why didn't you just stop when you got $\pm i-1=x$?

Comment: .... because ..... I'm an idiot?  .... I was so intent on thinking that as a variable to solve and $\pm i$ as nothing specific, I just didn't realize I actually .... had it solved.  That's quite a dope slap.